# Smallest natural number and greatest integer function

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

For $x\in R$
let [x] denote the greatest integer $\leq x$. Largest natural number $n$ for which

$E = [\pi/2]+[\pi/2+1/100]+[\pi/2+2/100]+[\pi/2+3/100]+\cdots+[\pi/2+n/100]<43$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well we know that $[\frac{\pi}{2}] = 1$. So, $n \leq 41$. Check that $[\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{41}{100}] = 1$. So, $n= 41$.